# Creating a JSON server hierarchy

Tags: json, request, json-server

I am using JSON-server to create a mock backend. I want the url I use to fetch data to look like this: `http://localhost:3000/org/org1/person/p1/configs`.

My current .json file looks like this:

```
"org":[{"id":"org1"}],

"person":[{"id":"p1", "orgId":"org1"}],

"configs":[{"foo": "foo1","personId": "p1"}]
```

Right now when I try a GET request to the url specified with the above JSON structure I get a 404 error. I do not know why it is happening or how to fix it. Any help on how to solve the problem?

Thank you for your help

Comment: If you already know personId, why do you need org id anyway?

Comment: I mean, you can just use `http://localhost:3000/person/p1/configs` anyway.

Comment: I can just use `http://localhost:3000/person/p1/configs`, but I am mocking an existing database that uses that url pattern and I want to stay consistent. Also, each person is under an org and they should not be accessible without going through the org first. Hope I am making sense

Comment: So that means there might be more than one person with `id` 'p1', sitting in different organizations?

Comment: No, every person is restricted to just one org. And they all must be part of one org there are no "loose" people